# Error Fitting Model in Conv Net Model : Value Error

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN model for a dataset which looks something like this:
It has 11 feature columns and a label column which is either 0 or 1.

The program:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

DATA_PATH = "testt.csv"


def load_data(data_path):
    """Loads training dataset from json file.

        :param data_path (str): Path to json file containing data
        :return X (ndarray): Inputs
        :return y (ndarray): Targets
    """

    
    data = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH)
    
    y = np.array(data["Label"])
    X = np.array(data.drop(labels = ["Label"],axis = 1) )
    
    return X, y



def prepare_datasets(test_size, validation_size):
    """Loads data and splits it into train, validation and test sets.

    :param test_size (float): Value in [0, 1] indicating percentage of data set to allocate to test split
    :param validation_size (float): Value in [0, 1] indicating percentage of train set to allocate to validation split

    :return X_train (ndarray): Input training set
    :return X_validation (ndarray): Input validation set
    :return X_test (ndarray): Input test set
    :return y_train (ndarray): Target training set
    :return y_validation (ndarray): Target validation set
    :return y_test (ndarray): Target test set
    """

    # load data
    X, y = load_data(DATA_PATH)

    # create train, validation and test split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)
    X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=validation_size)

    # add an axis to input sets
    X_train = X_train[..., np.newaxis]
    X_validation = X_validation[..., np.newaxis]
    X_test = X_test[..., np.newaxis]

    return X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test


def build_model(input_shape):
    """Generates CNN model

    :param input_shape (tuple): Shape of input set
    :return model: CNN model
    """

    # build network topology
    model = keras.Sequential()

    # 1st conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # 2nd conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # 3rd conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # flatten output and feed it into dense layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

    # output layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    return model




if __name__ == "__main__":

    # get train, validation, test splits
    X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test = prepare_datasets(0.25, 0.2)

    # create network
    input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)
    model = build_model(input_shape)

    # compile model
    optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser,
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.summary()

    # train model
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation), batch_size=32, epochs=30)
```

I am getting this error when I try to run this:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
1852   try:
-> 1853     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
1854   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,11,1,1], [3,3,1,32].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
1854   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
1855     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1856     raise ValueError(str(e))
1857
1858   return c_op

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,11,1,1], [3,3,1,32].

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, each datum has features of size [11] and label of size [1]. Thus your overall dataset has dimension X = [n_examples,11] and Y = [n_examples,1].

`Conv2D` is not the right operation to use in this case. `Conv2D` expects a set of 2D feature plane inputs (i.e. expected data size [n_examples,n_feature_planes,width,height]). It is commonly used on RGB images where each color represents a dimension along n_feature_planes.

If you expect your data vector of size [11] for each example to be spatially related (for instance, a 1D audio vector would be spatially related), you could use `Conv1D` in which case an input of size [n_examples,n_feature_vectors,length_of_feature_vector] would be used (where length_of_feature_vector in this case is 11. Thus, you would expand your data from size [n_examples,11] to size [n_examples,1,11] and then you can use `Conv1D`.

However, if your features are not spatially related (e.g. are distinct attributes), you should not use convolutional layers.